# MonoTouch/MT Garbage Collector: how to correctly release my views/class members (simple example)?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Have a look at the sample below which is not completely implemented but demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```
public class MyClass : UIView
{
  private UIView SubView;
  private UILabel ALabelInTheSubView;

  public override ViewDidLoad()
  {
  }

  // Imagine our view has a button. When clicked, a new sub view is added.
  public void HandleButtonAddView()
  {
    // Assign a new view to the SubView member and add a label.
    this.SubView = new UIView();
    this.ALabelInTheSubView = new UILabel("A label");
    this.SubView.AddSubView(this.ALabelInTheSubView);

    // Add the SubView to myself.
    this.AddSubView( this.SubView );
  }

  // Imagine our view has another button. When clicked, the sub view is removed.
  public void HandleButtonRemoveView()
  {
    this.SubView.RemoveFromSuperView();    
  }
}
```

- If I click the button to add the subview, the member variables `SubView` and `ALabelInTheSubView` are assigned new instances of `UIView` and `UILabel`.
- If I then click the button to remove the subview, `SubView` gets removed from super view.
- After `this.SubView.RemoveFromSuperView()` the members `SubView` and `ALabelInTheSubView` **still have references to the view or label**, hence no memory will be released yet. Correct so far?
- If I now click the button to add the sub view again, the members will be overwritten with NEW instances of `UIView` and `UILabel`.

**QUESTION**: Does the GC now know that it can now safely dispose the **previously** assigned `UIView` and `UILabel`? I mean, all references should be gone. Or do I have to call `this.SubView.Dispose() and this.ALabelInTheSubView.Dispose()` after removing from superview? And is disposing the label necessary at all, since it is a child node of the UIView, which just got removed and disposed (which would mean I always have to dispose from bottom to top)?

**ADD. SIDE-QUESTION:**
If I call Dispose() on an object this IS still referenced - is that a a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, the garbage collector will now consider the two previous instances of the objects to not be reachable from anywhere, and will be collected the next time the GC runs.

You do not need to call Dispose() manually.   The only reason to call Dispose() manually is in cases where you know that the object you are pointing to is some large object and you want to make sure that the memory is released immediately, and not wait for the GC to kick-in at some point in the future.

What happens when you call Dispose () on the object, is that we internally release the reference to the Objective-C object and we set the Handle property on the object to null.   This means that if you try to call another method on a disposed object, you will get a nice exception.

Comment: Hm, I had a real-world example in which GC didn't seem to get it. I have a view controller which creates its view in LoadView(). It then adds a content view which has a CATiledLayer and all this is embedded in a UIScrollView. All of these views/layers are assigned to member variables. Hitting a button removes the top (content) view and recreates everything, assigning new instances to all the members. If I don't dispose eveything, I'll run OOM pretty quickly. Is that b/c GC just does not kick in (yet)? But it really should if close to OOM I thought?

Comment: Just retried it and of course you are right Miguel. :-) I could not believe it and trile-checked my code and found a typo which cause reallocating a view over and over without ever removing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just reuse your SubView instead of making a new one each time.  So create it in ViewDidLoad, store it in a member variable, and reuse it.

I don't think the extra memory will be a problem, and you won't have to worry about the GC at all.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I just want to understand it. But it could also be that every time a really different view is created, then I could not reuse it. The question also is: there is nothing OBVIOUSLY holding a reference, but could it be that something in CocoaTouch still keeps a reference?

Comment: MonoTouch cleans up everything in the Objective-C world in the Dispose() method of IDisposable, you explicitly call Dispose() if you wanted more control and know when you're completely finished with UIKit or NS objects.  It is not required though, the GC will call Dispose() automatically when the managed object is collected.  My answer was aimed to help you get the job done quicker, but I can see where sometimes the question is meant to help understand whats going on.