# Need help to understand following crash log

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin

I am experiencing a strange app crash. I narrowed down the problem to one particular visual component. The app crashes when i navigate back and forth to the screen with this component several time. The strange thing is that same component does not cause crashes on another screen. The problem is that the app does not throw any error when running in debug more. The only thing I see is the crash report in device's log.

I am not sure what code from this component should I provide here. Thus, I will describe what it does in general words. Majority of the layout is coded in xib file which I am loading at runtime. This xib file has number of controls, and UIScrollView is one of the main container. At runtime, I am adding few more UIViews to this scroll view. I am also performing some custom drawing on main CALayer of these added UIViews.

It would be create if somebody can help me narrow down the problem. Also, how can I get more precise report if the issue does not throw any exceptions during debugging?

UPDATE1:

I did further investigations and I think the problem can be narrowed to possibly incorrect disposing. Very similar case is described here (the first comment under the answer). https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359686/3507404

UPDATE2:

It happened that the crash is related to CALayerDelegate. I narrowed down the issue to simple example here. [CALayerDelegate disposing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25640609/3507404)

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b9731f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b9dd792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b923fd8 abort + 72
3   MyApp                           0x00568df4 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2335)
4   MyApp                           0x00571dd8 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (mini.c:6744)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3b9d7f90 _sigtramp + 40
6   UIKit                           0x3302635c -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews] + 352
7   UIKit                           0x331432d4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willRemoveSubviewWantingAutolayout:] + 44
8   UIKit                           0x332c2056 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 198
9   UIKit                           0x33028af0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 56
10  UIKit                           0x3302b3b6 -[UIView dealloc] + 374
11  MyApp                           0x005fb940 invoke_objc_method_implementation (monotouch-glue.m:1341)
12  MyApp                           0x005fb998 monotouch_dealloc_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:1383)
13  MyApp                           0x005fb940 invoke_objc_method_implementation (monotouch-glue.m:1341)
14  MyApp                           0x005fb780 monotouch_release_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:1370)
15  MyApp                           0x005fb4bc monotouch_release_managed_ref (monotouch-glue.m:1296)
16  MyApp                           0x000f0fa0 (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject:monotouch_release_managed_ref + 88
17  MyApp                           0x000c6228 MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject:ReleaseManagedRef (.pmcs-compat.NSObject.cs:197)
18  MyApp                           0x000c658c MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject/NSObject_Disposer:Drain (.pmcs-compat.NSObject2.cs:1320)
19  MyApp                           0x00234d48 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 196
20  MyApp                           0x00573eb4 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:6610)
21  MyApp                           0x005b00f2 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2827)
22  MyApp                           0x005379f6 native_to_managed_trampoline_MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject_NSObject_Disposer_Drain (registrar.m:135)
23  Foundation                      0x311f7c6e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
24  CoreFoundation                  0x307d9208 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
25  CoreFoundation                  0x307d86d6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
26  CoreFoundation                  0x307d6eca __CFRunLoopRun + 618
27  CoreFoundation                  0x30741eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
28  CoreFoundation                  0x30741c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
29  GraphicsServices                0x3566865e GSEventRunModal + 134
30  UIKit                           0x3308e148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
31  MyApp                           0x000f6454 (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain + 268
32  MyApp                           0x000d2468 MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:Main (.pmcs-compat.UIApplication.cs:75)
33  MyApp                           0x00059144 KarmaMobile.iOS.Application:Main (Main.cs:46)
34  MyApp                           0x00234d48 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 196
35  MyApp                           0x00573eb4 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:6610)
36  MyApp                           0x005b00f2 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2827)
37  MyApp                           0x005b3c78 mono_runtime_exec_main (object.c:4052)
38  MyApp                           0x005b3ac8 mono_runtime_run_main (object.c:3678)
39  MyApp                           0x0056250c mono_jit_exec (driver.g.c:1009)
40  MyApp                           0x005e69a0 main (main.m:489)
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b8bdab4 start + 0
```

Comment: Well, you're tripping over a garbage pointer.  Either the pointer was never properly initialized or the object it addressed has been released.